# What are things to consider while writing a given piece of data to files for 32-bit and 64-bit applications?

Tags: c, file, struct, cross-platform

I have 3 applications. One is writer (32-bit) and other two are readers (one is 32-bit and another is 64-bit).
The writer will write a given data to two files, one will be read by 32-bit application and another will be read by 64-bit application.
The data is in the form of a struct that contain pointers which point to data buffer. Following is the one :

```
typedef struct userMap {
    char            customer_refid[256];
    char            cookieId[64];
    char            *authPayload;
    struct userMap *hh_prev;
    struct userMap *hh_next;
};
```

To write this struct in file for 64-bit application, the only thought in my mind is to convert 32-bit pointers to 64-bit pointers. I mean converting `char *authPayload` to `char *__ptr64 authPayload` to serve the purpose.

What other things I should consider to achieve the same since my `fread()` call made by 64-bit application is returning corrupted buffer if I write the struct as it is?

Note: authPayload points to some data buffer and I will be using `fwrite()` to write this struct to file.

Comment: The whole premise of the question seems wrong. Pointers only have meaning within a single process. You can't (in general) write pointers out and expect to use them in any sensible manner outside that process. Unless it points to shared memory or the system has special properties like a single address space. In all other cases, the writer needs to serialise and the reader needs to deserialise the data.

Comment: @kaylum I have updated the content, writing pointers means writing data buffer pointed by these pointers.

Comment: If that is the case then what does the pointer size have to do with anything? Since you are not writing the pointer value out why does it matter what the size is?

Comment: @kaylum But the buffer is corrupted, thats why I thing it has to do something with pointers, since the pointer size determines the next location where the data has to be written.

Comment: Your conclusion from the available information does not make sense. There could be many many things that cause corruption. It is not logical to conclude that the problem is caused by different pointer sizes on writer and reader where the pointer is not even transferred. Rather than just guessing it is much better to debug the problem directly with a debugger and/or debug print statements. But we can't help you any more than that unless you show a [mcve].

Comment: You need to show your write and read code. We can't help if we don't know what your code is doing.